# Changes to my Angular js file will not show

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, nginx

I am trying to figure out why changes to my app's angular js file will not show.

I am running a Django app and every time I make changes to the app I do a `collectstatic` and `compileall`. The changes would be to a grid table's row name. I have completely changed the name then ran those commands.

What I see after restarting the Nginx server and uwsgi would be the old table row names. Am I missing something here? Every other change that I have made seems to be working fine.

Comment: I think this might be a browser cache issue. you can do a hard refresh (ctrl + F5) to get the new file to be served.

you can install some cache busting plugins for which your angular app will get the latest copies of the source code.

Comment: Thank you. I never would have known.